# Need help pulling multiple reg values from multiple servers

Tags: registry

My code thus far:

```
import-module remoteregistry
$key = 
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols'
$servers = get-content C:\temp\myComputers.txt
FOREACH ($SERVER IN $servers) {
TRY {
Get-Regvalue -CompuerName $SERVER -Key 
"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols" - 
Recurse | OUT-FILE C:\TEMP\new-reg-results.txt -Append
} CATCH {
ADD-CONTENT '$SERVER.Name Not Found' C:\TEMP\new-reg-results.txt
}
}
```

I'm trying to pull all the keys and values for those keys under the key I've defined, but I the script runs for a second, then stops with no errors, but no output file is generated at all.  Any thoughts?

Comment: There is a type at the following file: Get-Regvalue -CompuerName $SERVER -Key . Did you mean to type ComputerName?